# Why `commit replace` left traces of login accounts on Cisco IOS-XR?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asr, cisco-ios-xr

Wiped the startup-config with `commit replace` on our ASR 9006 routers in the global config. Noticed that after a console timeout that it prompts for an account to login. Logging in with an old account proved worthless. Prompt after timeout is shown here below. The strange part is the attempt by user "unknown".

```
Username: user
Password: RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:Jan  4 09:22:30.338 : exec[65755]: %SECURITY-LOGIN-4-AUTHEN_FAILED : Failed authentication attempt by user '<unknown>' from 'console' on 'con0_RSP0_CPU0'
```

Mind you that the router hasn't been restarted and the nvram wasn't erased.

Why was I prompted for an account if no account is configured on the router? Do I solve this by a simple reload?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes, I am having a hard time finding a question here. Are you wondering why it logged a login attempt by user 'unknown' on the console? I would assume that was your test and you either didn't enter a username or something else interrupted the login process.